# Handling horizontal swipe on control in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

So let's say I have stackpanel on the left edge with width 200px. Now I want to handle horizontal swipe from left to right on this panel and show additional panel. Then handle swipe from right to left to hide it.

I tried handling page's `ManipulationStarted` and `ManipulationDelta` events, but it doesn't seem to have any effect at least with mouse. Any ideas, what could be an easy way to implement that?

What I've tried:
Handle page's swipe events and on the beginning of swipe check, if it was started in bounds of stackpanel, else I ignore it.

If swipe's delta was more then positive 40, looks like swipe was from left to right.

My XAML file:

```
// standard stuff of page
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" x:Name="Panel"/>
</Grid>
```

// continue standard stuff

C# file:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.ManipulationDelta += MainPage_ManipulationDelta;
        this.ManipulationStarted += MainPage_ManipulationStarted;
    }

    private void MainPage_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("heh");
        if (e.Position.X < 200)
        {
            initialPoint = e.Position;
            isSwiping = true;
        }
    }

    private void MainPage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.IsInertial && isSwiping)
        {
            Point currentPoint = e.Position;
            if (currentPoint.X - initialPoint.X >= 40)
            {
                isSwiping = false;
                e.Complete();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("finished swipe :)");
            }
        }
    }

    private Point initialPoint;
    private Boolean isSwiping;
```

(Again omitted default empty page)

Comment: What is it exactly you are looking for? A better approach? Or doesn't it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set ManipulationMode on a control e.g. ManipulationMode="TranslateX" and have the control respond to hit-testing (i.e. if it does not have a background - set the Background to Transparent) to receive manipulation events.

Then again - why not just use a ListView that has built-in support for swipes?

Comment: Can you specify please, how does ListView support swipes? I walked through events and still don't get it

Comment: It's enabled by default for item selection in a ListView (`IsSwipeEnabled="True"` by default). You can swipe an item to select it.